# Find string within JSON with Python

Tags: python, json

I'm currently getting a very long JSON and I'm trying to pick out 2 pieces of information from it through Python 2.7.

The JSON looks roughly like this:

```
{
  'device': [
    {
      'serial': '00000000762c1d3c',
      'registered_id': '019'
    },
    {
      'serial': '000000003ad192f2',
      'registered_id': '045'
    },
    {
      'serial': '000000004c9898aa',
      'registered_id': '027'
    }
  ],
}
```

Within this JSON I'm looking for a specific serial that might match with one in the JSON. If it does, it should print out the registered_id as well.

I've tried using a simple script, even without the registered_id but I'm getting nowhere.:

```
if '00000000762c1d3c' not in data['device']:
        print 'not there'
else:
        print 'there'
```

Thanks for your suggestions!

Comment: Write a for loop to iterate over the devices.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`date['device']` contains a list of objects, so you should treat it as such and iterate over them:

```
for element in data['device']:
    if element['serial'] == '00000000762c1d3c':
        print 'there'
        print element['registered_id']
        break
else:
    print 'not there'
```

This is using the somehow lesser-known `for-else` construct: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#break-and-continue-statements-and-else-clauses-on-loops

Comment: is it pissuble to check if a string is contained at all in the serial. lets say you want to search and store all the serial number that have a `3` in it. and return the first and second serial number in an object or array....

Answer (score 8):

first, your input isn't json. Json uses double quotes. But suppose you successfully *loaded* it with json, it's now a dictionary, called `d`.

Then you can scan all sub-dicts of `d` and test `serial` key against your value, stopping when found using `any` and a generator comprehension:

```
print(any(sd['serial']=='00000000762c1d3c' for sd in d['device']))
```

returns `True` if serial found `False` otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help you:

```
if [x for x in data['device'] if x.get('serial')=='00000000762c1d3c']:
  print "IN"
else:
  print "NOT"
```

[Python: List Comprehensions](http://www.secnetix.de/olli/Python/list_comprehensions.hawk) can be used to construct lists in a very natural, easy way, like a mathematician is used to do.